# Installing python-sexy?

Tags: compiz, python

I'm trying to install it by doing `sudo apt-get install python-sexy` but it tells me

```
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
```

I couldn't find any info on google so I'm wondering if this isn't that common.

I found something [here](http://pkgs.org/package/python-sexy#ubuntu-10.04) but if I download it from there it won't be up to date I guess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note: The python bindings for libsexy have been [removed for Maverick](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sexy-python/+publishinghistory) as it was determined they are [no longer needed](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=568546).

Comment: oh, ok then. i was going to use compiz and it said it wasn't installed but was optional, so i figured it would be better to install it.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you were going to develop something with it :) (Still, let's leave this unanswered until I or someone else finds a good way to install it, even if it's deprecated. Might be useful for someone)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answer would be to compile it yourself but as noted, this is not needed anymore. We only use this in ccsm to put an image inside a GtkEntry but the next release should remove that since GTK+ itself allows this now.